# Powershell wrapping lines of text on import

Tags: powershell

Am trying to use powershell to scan through a log file and find occurences of a particular pattern.  So far my tests of searching with regex are failing but I have noticed something that I think may be the cause.  running a get-content on the log file in question brings back the file but wraps what would be a single line when displayed in notepad++ on to multiple lines.

Is there anyway to stop powershell from wrapping the text or is it hard coded in to the fact that the window is the limit for line length in powershell?

Answer (score 3):

`Out-File` may chomp the lines, by default it writes lines with width of the host window, default is `80`. Maybe try using `Set-Content` or give `Out-File` a `-Width` sufficiently big.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the lines are wrapped in the console is just because of the way that it displays text. It will not affect the regex.

That being said you shouldn't need to use `Get-Content` for a regex search. `Select-String` should be able to do the job itself.

Comment: apologies I was assuming that the -path argument would be using the same method as get-content to actually read the file and carry out the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Applications and operating systems usually represent a newline with one or two control characters, typically carriage return (backtick r) and linefeed (backtick n).

Try splitting your content, by explicitly adding the `-delimiter` parameter followed by one of these control characters.

```
get-content file.log -delimiter "`n"
```